# Identify most variable rows within multiple subsets of a data.frame and merge this information into a final data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data.frame named `data` containing 18472 rows by 2229 columns. The last column of this data.frame (`data$bin`) contains a bin number from 1:7, although this may be dynamic later down the road. What I'd like to accomplish is to identify the 25 most variable rows for each bin and create a final data.frame with these. Ultimately this would result in a data.frame with 25*7 rows by 2228 columns. I am able to identify variable rows but I'm not sure how to preform this on all bins within `data`:

```
> # identify variable rows
> library(genefilter)
> mostVarRows = head(order(rowVars(data), decreasing=TRUE), 25)
```

Data looks something like this:

```
> head(data[(ncol(data)-3):ncol(data)])
              D6_NoSort_6000x3b_CCCCCGCCCTGA D6_NoSort_2250b_ATTATACTATTT D6_EcadSort_6000x3b_CACGACCTCCAC bin
0610005C13RIK                              0                            0                                0   2
0610007P14RIK                              0                            0                                0   6
0610009B22RIK                              0                            0                                0   3
0610009L18RIK                              0                            0                                0   2
0610009O20RIK                              0                            0                                0   3
0610010B08RIK                              0                            0                                0   6
```

I need to extract out the most variant rows from each bin into a separate data.frame!

Comment: What is a bin, and what do you consider to make the data more variable? Can you illustrate with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below I create a mock data set. For future reference, the burden is on you to do this since you know what you want better than I do.

```
# create mock data
set.seed(1)
data<-replicate(1000,rnorm(500,500,100))
data<-data.frame(data,bins= sample(c(1:7),500,replace=TRUE)) # create bins column
```

Next I find the variance of each row (assuming this is how you want to define "most variable"). Then I sort by bin and variance (greatest to lowest).

```
data$var_by_row<-apply(data[,1:1000],1,var) # find variance of each row
data<-data[order(data$bins, -data$var_by_row),] # sort by bin and variance
```

Since the data is sorted properly, it remains to take the first 25 observations of each bin and stack them together. You were definitely on the right track with your use of order() and head(). The do.call() step afterwards is necessary to stack the head() results and is probably what you're looking for.

```
data_sub_list<-by(data,INDICES = data$bins, head,n=25) # grab the first 25 observations of each bin
data_sub<-do.call('rbind',data_sub_list) # the above returns a list of 7 data frames...one per bin. this stacks them

> table(data_sub$bins) # each bin appears 25 times.

 1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
25 25 25 25 25 25 25 

> nrow(data_sub) # number of rows is 25*7
[1] 175
```